# Can't install rails on my Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am trying to install Rails on my Mac Version 10.9.5 and something is not working as when I try to see which version of Rails I have installed I get the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

$ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.
```

If I try to run that command, this is what I am getting...

```
sudo gem install rails
Password:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/ppmartins/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
Reason: image not found
```

Any idea about what's happening and how to solve this issue?

Thank you all.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/820364/ruby-installation-issues-with-rvm may be helpful...?

Comment: you should check this out http://rvm.io/

Comment: @mymlyn The error message looks like he is already using rvm...?

Comment: Thank you guys! Apparently it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to never use your system Ruby to install Gems. System Ruby is a version of Ruby that ships with your Mac. OSX uses Ruby for various tasks, so it is best to leave it alone and not risk corrupting any Gems.

Instead, you should use Ruby version managers to install versions of Ruby that your system won't rely on. Using sudo is also not necessary for these versions. If you find yourself needing to do this, you might be (ab)using your system Ruby.

Personally I use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) since it integrates well with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), but there are others such RVM as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following http://installrails.com/

It runs you step by step through setting up an environment on your computer. :D 
It's pretty straight forward compared with googling rbenv, RVM etc

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- Dump `rvm` and use `rbenv`. You haven't set it up correctly anyway
- Don't use sudo when installing gems
- Make sure your don't use system Ruby from '/Library'

So,

1. Install Homebrew http://brew.sh
2. Install Rbenv `brew install rbenv`
3. Install Ruby Build `brew install ruby-build`
4. Install Ruby `rbenv install 2.1.2`
5. Make it a default interpreter `rbenv global 2.1.2`

That's the gist of it. There might be some things you need to do manually like adding `rbenv` path to your `.bash_profile`.

**Update** I was downvoted? Haha, why?